# How to force Local Notification even when the user turns off the Notification in System setting screen(Settings->AppName->Notifications)

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm using below code to push Local Notification. This code works only when the user turn on the Notification in  System setting screen(Settings->AppName->Notifications)

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func notifyUserNotification()
{
    let trigger =  UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = "You have a new Recording !!"
    content.subtitle = "You have recorded 10mins recording"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "customNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)


}
```

Comment: If it is possible to ignore notification settings, then everybody would do it, so apparently it is impossible

Comment: Jailbreak your device :)